# Please help me understad how to achieve the probability outcome

Tags: probability

The wheel spinner is equally divided into $5$ even parts. Each part is labeled $(0,1,2,3,4)$. This spinner is spun twice.

A. What is the sample space?

B. What is the probability of...

a. an odd number on the first spin and an even number on the second spin (NOTE: 0 is considered an even number)?

b. a sum greater than 4?

c. Even numbers on both spins?

d. a sum that is odd?

e. the same number on both spins?

Comment: Lots of questions, but if you get the first okay the rest should follow.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A sample space is a set of all possible outcomes for an experiment.   What would be an appropriate set that describes the possible outcomes of this process?

What are the probability weights of these outcomes.   If you chose wisely all outcomes could be equally probable (so, are they?).

Identify the events you are asked to find, as subsets of the sample space. Thus use your probability measure to evaluate the probabilities of these subsets.

Answer (score 1):

A. You can choose the sample space to be $\Omega = \{ (i,j) | i,j \in \{0,...,4\} \}$, with $p \{k\} = {1 \over 5^2}$ for $k \in \Omega$.

B. For a,...,e, just count the number of elements in $\Omega$ that satisfy the given condition.

For example, take a:

The pairs are $ (i,j)$ where $i$ is odd and $j$ is even. It is straightforward to see that there are 6 such pairs, hence the probability is $6 {1 \over 5^2}$.